# How do get information from a populated dropdownlist before calling a method to fill the details grid?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, angularjs

What is the proper way to do this ? Here are the statements one after another but since javascript is async I am guessing $score.lastItem does not exist when the 2nd function is called? So Do I put this 2nd function in a callback of the 1st?

```
 //1st Call this on inital load to populate Congresses dropdownlist
ccResource.query(function (data) {
    $scope.ccList.length = 0;
    angular.forEach(data, function (ccData) {
        $scope.ccList.push(ccData);
    })

    $scope.lastItem = $scope.ccList[$scope.ccList.length - 1];
});

//2nd after populating $scope.lastItem run this to populate grid on initial load (using id from selected item in dropdownlist)
cgResource.query({ id: $scope.lastItem.congressNumber }, function (data) {
    $scope.usersList = data;
});

//ngGrid
$scope.userGrid = {
    data: 'usersList',
    multiSelect: false,
    selectedItems: $scope.selectedUsers,
    enableColumnResize: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'firstname', displayName: 'First Name', width: '25%' },
        { field: 'lastname', displayName: 'Last Name', width: '25%' }
    ]
};
```

Comment: if there'a dependency, why not include the 2nd fn call in the 1st fn? You can't populate the detail grid until there's a selected item right? (if I understand your script comments). What does `$scope.lastItem` have to do with the selected item that populates the grid?

Comment: $scope.lastItem is the last item in the item.. When the page is first loaded I want it to default to the last item in the table (last CongressId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.You can do

```
//1st Call this on inital load to populate Congresses dropdownlist
ccResource.query(function (data) {
    $scope.ccList.length = 0;
    angular.forEach(data, function (ccData) {
        $scope.ccList.push(ccData);
    })

    $scope.lastItem = $scope.ccList[$scope.ccList.length - 1];

    //2nd after populating $scope.lastItem run this to populate grid on initial load (using id from selected item in dropdownlist)
    cgResource.query({
        id: $scope.lastItem.congressNumber
    }, function (data) {
        $scope.usersList = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks.. For some reason I have trouble going from C# style to Javascripts function in a function in a function style... I guess this is called  a 'promise' ?